# filter off NaNs in a large DataFrame with headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large number of time series, with blanks on certain dates for some of them. I read that with xlwings from an XL sheet:

```
Y0 = xw.Range('SomeRangeinXLsheet').options(pd.DataFrame, index=True , header=3).value
```

I'm trying to create a filter to run regressions on those series so I have to take out the void dates. If I :

```
print(Y0.iloc[:,[i]]==Y0.iloc[:,[i]])
```

I get a proper series of true/false for my column number i, fine.
I'm then stuck, can't find a way to filter the whole df, with the true/false for that column, or even just extract that clean series as a pd.Series.
I need them one by one to adapt my independent variables' dates to those of my each of these separately.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use [`df.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: I tried, but couldn't display it properly i suppose, I have error messages such as:
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 56

Comment: OK, then I recommend searching here on StackOverflow for each error message you get one by one until you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem, but if you want to for check NULLs in a specific column and drop those rows, you can try this -

```
import pandas as pd
df = df[pd.notnull(df['column_name'])]
```

For deleting NaNs, `df.dropna()` should work, as suggested in the previous answer. If it is not working, you can try replacing NaNs with a placeholder text and try deleting the rows that contain that placeholder text.

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].replace(np.nan, 'delete-it', regex = True)
df = df[df["column_name"] != 'delete-it']
```

Hope this helps!